# How can i filter my data by foreign key before lucene searching?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lucene.net

I want to use Lucene search in my projects, because its fast, but there's a problem.

I have DB tables users and friendship. I want to find friends of user by search form. With lucene I can only find all users by search query, get their ids, put them to entity framework and then take only friends of user, but what if users in system ten millions, and friends of that user just a few? So I need to take friends of user and then filter them by search query. How can i do that? I heard about Linq to Lucene, but I not sure that it's what i need. Please, help my with my trouble.

P.S. Sorry for my english, I am from Ukraine and don't speak english wery well:)

I've found solution. I will store friends ids in the index and find user friends by these ids. It is not the best solution, because index will be often edited, but I can't implement another idea.

Comment: If a user has just a few friends than why would you index the users at all? If I were you I would first try to use some sort of online searching (eg. get the list of friends and iterate over them). Have you tried something like this?

Comment: Hmm... Well, may be you are right. But what if user have 10k of friends?

Comment: Than your question stands, and you can start praying that somebody will give you a usefull answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using [filters](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d3/dc7/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_filter.html). This is a short demo that would limit the results to only those documents that have FriendsWith:Beta. This would require reindexing 
documents affected by changed friendship connections. The [TermsFilter](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d9/d81/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_terms_filter.html) class can be found in the contrib package.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Directory = Lucene.Net.Store.Directory;
using Version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    public static class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var directory = new RAMDirectory();
            var analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();

            using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)) {
                var users = new [] { "Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
                var friendships = new Dictionary<String, String[]> {
                    { "Alfa", new [] { "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" } },
                    { "Beta", new [] { "Gamma", "Delta" } },
                    { "Gamma", new [] { "Delta" } },
                    { "Delta", new String[0] } // Noone likes Delta.
                };

                foreach (var userName in users) {
                    var doc = new Document();
                    doc.Add(new Field("Name", userName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));

                    foreach (var friendName in friendships[userName]) {
                        doc.Add(new Field("FriendsWith", friendName, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    }

                    writer.AddDocument(doc);
                }

                writer.Commit();
            }

            // This should be the real query provided by the user (city, age, description, ...)
            var query = new MatchAllDocsQuery();

            // Create a filter limiting the result to those being friends with the current user,
            // in this example the user "Beta".
            var filter = new TermsFilter();
            filter.AddTerm(new Term("FriendsWith", "Gamma"));

            var reader = IndexReader.Open (directory, readOnly: true);
            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

            var result = searcher.Search (query, filter, 10);
            foreach(var topDoc in result.ScoreDocs) {
                var doc = searcher.Doc(topDoc.Doc);
                var foundName = doc.Get ("Name");
                Console.WriteLine("Matched user '{0}'", foundName);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```